# How to get table values with stored procedure, cursor and for loop?

Tags: mysql, for-loop, stored-procedures, cursor, procedure

I am building a stored procedure that uses a cursor and a loop. I am understanding how the code works but I am having trouble creating a condition. I fail to understand how I can call the code to check for null values in certain cells depending on the input parameter.

Explanation of my code:
I am checking if a member has any overdue books. In a table that I have called 'borrowedby' has variables 'MemberID', 'ReturnDate' and 'BookID'. ReturnDate is the date that the book has been returned. The input parameter 'memberIDEN' must equal 'MemberID' and checks if 'ReturnDate' is null. If it is null then I print out memberID and the books that are overdue.

How do I create a condition that checks if 'ReturnDate' is null from table 'borrowedby'?

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists overdueBooks  //

delimiter //
create procedure overdueBooks  (in memberid INT)

begin
declare returnCheck date;
declare finished int default 0;
declare overdueList varchar (100) default "";

declare cursor_data cursor for 
select MemberID 
from borrowedby 
where memberid = MemberID;

declare continue handler for not found set finished = 1;

open cursor_data;

get_members: loop
    fetch cursor_data into overdueList;
    
    if returnCheck is not null 
        then
            leave get_members;
    end if;
end loop get_members;
close cursor_data;
end
//
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that SP is excess.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM borrowedby 
WHERE @memberIDEN = MemberID
  AND returnCheck IS NULL
```

This query returns all non-returned books for specified memeber.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that an sp with cursor is not the way to go but.. There are a number of things wrong with the sp

1. You are not grabbing all the fields you need in the cursor select
2. You have correctly declared a handler but you don't test in the loop so your loop is infinite.
3. The fetch should fetch all columns it needs
4. Once fetched you aren't doing anything with the data if you do find overdue books.
5. You aren't catering for the case where a borrower has a combination of overdue and returned.

The corrected SP given

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T
(MemberID INT, ReturnDate DATE,BookID INT);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1,NULL,1),(1,NULL,3),(2,'2020-11-02',2);

delimiter //

create procedure P  (in memberIDEN INT)

begin
declare returnCheck date;
declare finished int default 0;
declare overdueList varchar (100) default "";

declare cursor_data cursor for 
select MemberID ,RETURNDATE from T where memberIDEN = MemberID;

declare continue handler for not found set finished = 1;

open cursor_data;

get_members: loop
    fetch cursor_data into overdueList,RETURNCHECK;
    
     IF FINISHED = 1 THEN
        LEAVE GET_MEMBERS;
    END IF;
        
    fetch cursor_data into overdueList,RETURNCHECK;
    
    if returnCheck is NULL then
            SELECT OVERDUELIST ' HAS OVERDUE BOOK(S)';
    end if;
end loop get_members;
close cursor_data;
end //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @P.Salmon, this actually explained a lot. I am still learning how cursors and procedures work. I am working on checking conditions with two tables now. Is there a way to print out overdueList if given bookID's?